# The extension of Egorov's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ is defined and continuous in the square $0\leq x\leq 1, 0 < y \leq 1$, and that $f(x)=\lim_{y\to 0}{f(x,y)}$ exists and is finite for $x$ in a measurable subset $E$ of $[0, 1]$.

for $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ satisfy $0<\varepsilon,\delta<1$, the set
    $E_{\varepsilon,\delta} = \left\{x\in E: |f(x,y)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon \text{ for all }0 < y< \delta \right\}$
    is measurable.

If $\{y_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a dense subset of $(0,\delta)$, show that
$$E_{\varepsilon,\delta} = \bigcap_{k}{\left\{x\in E: |f(x,y_k)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon \right\}}.$$

In this question,I have a deal,but I can not sure that it is true or not.

for $y \in(0,\delta) $ we can find a subseq $\{y_{k_j}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of $\{y_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ below $y$ and converge to $y$

Fix $x$, {$f(x,y)\gt y$} $\subseteq$ {$f(x,y)\gt y_{k_j}$}

so $\left\{x\in E: |f(x,y)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon \text{ for all }y< \delta \right\}$ $\subseteq$ ${\left\{x\in E: |f(x,y_k)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon \right\}}$

and {$f(x,y)\gt y$} =$\cap_{j=1}^{\infty}$ {$f(x,y)\gt y_{k_j}$}

Therefore,$$E_{\varepsilon,\delta} = \bigcap_{k}{\left\{x\in E: |f(x,y_k)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon \right\}}.$$

Is my opinion correct ? Can you give me some suggestion.Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^* \in E_{\epsilon, \delta}$, and let $k \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$. Since $y_k \in (0,\delta)$, we have $|f(x^*, y_k) - f(x^*)| \leq \epsilon$. Since $k$ was arbitrary, this shows that
$$
x^* \in \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \big\{x \in E\ |\!:\ |f(x,y_k) - f(x)| \leq \epsilon\big\}. \tag{*}\label{star}
$$

Conversely, suppose that \eqref{star} holds, and let $y \in (0,\delta)$. Let $I$ be an infinite subset of $\{1, 2, \dots\}$ such that
$$
y = \lim_{\substack{i\rightarrow\infty\\i \in I}} y_i.
$$
Then, since for every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, $|f(x^*,y_n) - f(x^*)| \leq \epsilon$, and since $f$ is continuous at $(x^*,y)$, we have
$$
|f(x^*,y) - f(x^*)| = \lim_{\substack{i\rightarrow\infty\\i \in I}} |f(x^*,y_i) - f(x^*)| \leq \epsilon,
$$
so that $x^* \in E_{\epsilon, \delta}$.